# Expectation Value of a 2 Particle System

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators

For a general $1$ particle system in a continuous Hilbert Space, the expectation value for an operator, $A$ , can be calculated:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\psi^*(x)A\psi(x)dx}$$

Does this generalize to a system of $2$ particles such that the expectation value is:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\psi^*(x_1, x_2)A\psi(x_1, x_2)dx_1dx_2}$$

For example, if we are trying to find the expectation value of: 
$$(x_1-x_2)$$
Would the solution be found using:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\psi^*(x_1, x_2)(x_1-x_2)\psi(x_1, x_2)dx_1dx_2}$$

Comment: If $A$ is defined on the space of single variable functions, how can it be applied to two variable functions?

Comment: @KeithMcClary, I am concerned specifically with operators that relate a property of both particles. Please see the edit.

Comment: Where are you getting a *continuous* Hilbert space from (maybe the term you’re searching for is rigged or separable)? Yes, your expression is sensible for multi-particle wave functions. You can also take the expectation value for some operator in a tensor product state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generalization written is correct. For example, the expectation value of $\hat{A}$ for a two-electron system with the wavefunction 
$$\Psi(x_1,x_2)=\psi(x_1)\psi(x_2)$$
can be written as $\langle\Psi|\hat{A}|\Psi\rangle$. That is,
$$ \langle\hat{A}\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Psi^*(x_1,x_2)\hat{A}\Psi(x_1,x_2)dx_1 dx_2, $$
regardless the form of $\hat{A}$.

If $\hat{A}$ works only on $x_1$, then 
$$ \langle\hat{A}\rangle=\int|\psi(x_2)|^2dx_2\int\psi^*(x_1)\hat{A}\psi(x_1)dx_1 $$

Comment: Great, thank you!